# How to get applications from taskmanager's tabs?

Tags: c#, windows, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve a complete processes list using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599663/retrieve-a-complete-processes-list-using-c)

How can I get a list of applications from the applications in Task Manager in C#?

Also, I'll want see hidden applications. Because, some applications do not appear in processes tab e.g Knignt Online.

What should I do?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
```

Comment: -I tried him too.it's not working.thanks.

Comment: It's not working conveys no information. What did you try? How did it fail?