# show running applications (alt-tab program list)

Tags: c#, process, alt-tab, processlist

Found the solution here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx

---

I'm trying to go a list of running applications, i found on several forums this solution:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var proc in processes)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
        Console.WriteLine(proc.MainWindowTitle);
}
```

exept this is not giving me the same list as when you press alt-tab. For example: firefox, explorer, and iexplore all return an empty/null MainWindowTitle. Is there another way to access this list? Maybe thru a windowsAPI?

I'm am using Windows 7 32bit

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/cb972d77-0892-4bf7-834d-c23b6dd5c03a/c--get-the-all-running-processes-and-applications.aspx

it may help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does)

Comment: Also see the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/210519/21567) which references a blog entry of Raymond Chen, that gives details.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hidden processes on Windows. Only processes you do not have (security) rights to see.

have a look at the below:

[Retrieve a complete processes list using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599663/retrieve-a-complete-processes-list-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I can see all the processes, but i cannot retreive the mainwindowtitle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (taken from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/cb972d77-0892-4bf7-834d-c23b6dd5c03a/c--get-the-all-running-processes-and-applications.aspx)), but I'm not sure it solves your problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetProcesses();
    GetApplications();
    Console.Read();
}
public static void GetProcesses()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ManagementClass MgmtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in MgmtClass.GetInstances())           
        Console.WriteLine("Name:" + mo["Name"] + "ID:" + mo["ProcessId"]);               

    Console.WriteLine();
}

public static void GetApplications()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
        try
        {
            if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Window Title:" + p.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Process Name:" + p.ProcessName.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Window Handle:" + p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Memory Allocation:" + p.PrivateMemorySize64.ToString());                     
            }
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve my problem. I am seeing all the processes but the getapplications function only gives me one running program (its own process).