# How can I get a list of processes running across multiple virtual desktops?

Tags: c#

I am working on Window 7 and I have multiple desktops by using the [Sysinternals Desktops utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx). I just want to list all the processes running across all the desktops.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processlist)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName + " " + p.Id + " " + p.MainWindowTitle); 
}
```

With this code I am able to get all the processes running on the current desktop, but I am not able to get the processes running inside different desktops.

Only Desktops is showing as a single process.

How can I get the child processes inside multiple desktops?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599663/retrieve-a-complete-processes-list-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Liam - if you follow the link, you'll see that Desktops Utility creates virtual machines. The topic is a little more complicated than what is covered in the "duplicate" question.

Comment: @Liam I believe it is not a duplicate since the other question does not relate to virtual desktop(s) at all.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Where do you find the word "machine" in that link? lol

Comment: @AlvinWong - Dang it... you're right. I'm not really in my element here... signing off. ;)

Comment: When you run the code with a virtual desktop, what output do you get?

Comment: @Liam Hi, This is not duplicate question.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Hi which function you are telling that is `Process.GetProcessesByName("remoteMachineName Or remoteMachine IP")` [Go to ProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx) but that function is for accessing the processes on remote machine.

Comment: @SimpalChaudhary - I read the linked article and misunderstood, thinking that the Desktop utility created actual virtual machines. If that were true, it would have a name and be accessible as a remote machine, but it's not true so that is irrelevant.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - its ok bro... now i got it. Actually Desktop utility creates virtual desktop only on local machine. Thanks Bro

Comment: Is there anyway we can do this using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup i got it.. after doing RnD.

I am using user32.dll and some of these methods.

If you also want to achieve some thing use these functions.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int _GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumDesktops(IntPtr hwinsta, EnumDesktopProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetProcessWindowStation();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr OpenDesktop(string lpszDesktop, uint dwFlags, bool fInherit, uint dwDesiredAccess);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);
```

By using these methods I am able to list down all the running processes on all the virtual desktop.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. It might help future visitors if you demonstrated how you used these functions to accomplish your goal, but +1 for answering your own question.